# SQL Error: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: product, admin, error, mysql, shopping-cart-price-rules

Every time I update my products in /admin I get this sql error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '2-0-0-1-1-375-0' for key 'EAA51B56FF092A0DCB795D1CEF812B7B', query
>   was: INSERT INTO `catalogrule_product`
>   (`rule_id`,`from_time`,`to_time`,`website_id`,`customer_group_id`,`product_id`,`action_operator`,`action_amount`,`action_stop`,`sort_order`,`sub_simple_action`,`sub_discount_amount`)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

It doesn't seem to actually affect anything but it kind of worries me.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache and re-indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backup the table `catalogrule_product`.
Truncate it.
Run the reindex process from the command line.
If something goes wrong, just restore you table.

Comment: What is the use for this table ? I'm really weary of truncating a table that I don't know much about. Also, should I also truncate table like catalogrule_product_price and other catalogrule_* tables ?

Comment: @Marus I have the same issue but not getting resolved after doing above the steps.Can you help out on this.

Comment: @CharulTyagi I have no other ideas

Comment: This trick doesn't solve the problem at all!